# how can i upload file more than 4 g size in c# ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, upload

I create upload project but I cant upload large size files. I read more articles and I try more to put this value in Max Length but I cant make it work.

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2000000000" delayNotificationTimeout="108000" executionTimeout="108000000000" />

<sessionState timeout="360000" sqlCommandTimeout="360000" stateNetworkTimeout="360000"></sessionState>
```

if i put 3 G i cant do it

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="3000000000" delayNotificationTimeout="108000" executionTimeout="108000000000" />
```

I have error in this line. I need to upload files more than 4 or 6 G 
note : i used MVC and Visual Studio 2013
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Even if you can, you should not. You should upload the file 'chunk by chunk'. You can read this article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43272/Uploading-Large-Files-Through-Web-Service. It is for web services but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 0):

set `maxRequestLength="4294967295"`

Answer (score 0):

Modify the maxAllowedContentLength setting in the web.config

```
       <system.webServer>
          <security>
            <requestFiltering>
              <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="(mention size)" />
            </requestFiltering>
          </security>
       </system.webServer>
```